# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent - From Service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity

I'm facing the following error when trying to open activity from **my Service.** 
The exception is: 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.sygic.aura flg=0x10000000 }

I'm trying to open some internal package "com.sygic.aura", and I don't even know if it has intent filter( if it doesn't - is there another way to open app?).

This is the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(package);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Please help

Comment: Did you list your Activity in your manifest.xml file ?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to load my activity but some other app activity. I want that the user will be able to open gps app from my app so I'm doing the above code with package = "com.sygic.aura", and it gives me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't send URL-location for the activity:

```
private Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+California");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
intent.setPackage(defaultGpsPackage);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

That way it works!